# CSV to list of ints and count occurrence of integers

Tags: python, csv

This feels like it should be super easy, but i'm struggling to find a solution.

I've got a CSV file full of ints

9,12,9,12,8,6,10,7,7,15,8,8,7,8,8,10,10,3,8

all I am trying to do is read the CSV file to a list of ints and use Counter from Collections to count the occurrence of each int, then save this info to a CSV file.

I've tried

```
import csv
from collections import Counter

with open('/Users/willturner/Desktop/caloHits.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    CaloHits = list(reader)

print Counter(10)
```

to get the number of 10's in the list. But I get

-> *TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable*

I've tired lots of different things but havn't had success with anything.

Comment: You never actually use the `Counter`. It would somehow have to interact with `CaloHits` would it not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by looping through the csv lines/rows and updating the counter object by each row.

```
import csv
from collections import Counter

calo_hits = Counter()
with open('/Users/willturner/Desktop/caloHits.csv') as f: # 'rb' is not necessary
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        calo_hits.update([int(n.strip()) for n in row if n.strip()])

print calo_hits[10]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually intialize the counter. Try this:

```
import csv
from collections import Counter

with open('/Users/willturner/Desktop/caloHits.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    calo_hits_counter = Counter(reader)

print calo_hist_counter[10]
```

Though, this will probably return 0. The reason being, when you load the CSV, the numbers are not actually converted to integers.

To get around this, you could either, check the count of the string `'10'`, ie, `calo_hist_counter['10']`.

Or, you could convert all the data you load to integers, by doing `calo_hits_counter = Counter(map(int, reader))`

As an aside, if all the data you are loading is in a single line, you don't really need the overhead of the `csv` library, you could do without it.

```
from collections import Counter

with open('/Users/willturner/Desktop/caloHits.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = f.read()
    calo_hits_counter = Counter(reader)
```

Comment: If the csv file has more than one line, this code will break badly.

Comment: using the csv lib method, I get traceback error

--> 6     calo_hits_counter = Counter(reader)

and TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' . Is this a problem on my end with python or a problem with the code?